# Update using ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Hi can someone tell me the problem with this please, and how to fix it.

I'm trying to update part of the page using ajax, I'm using the basic code that comes with a new mvc project.

The logon page has this:

```
 <span id="error"/>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="error"})) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>

            <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

and the controller like so:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                         Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            return "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
        }
```

Basically what I have done is embeded the login form into a modal popup. 
if the entered user credentials fail I want the error to be displayed inside the modal popup, not go off to another page.

The above code is just creating a blank page with the text "The user name or password provided is incorrect."...I need it to be displayed in the modal dialog (jQuery).

Comment: Can you show us the LogonModel? I assume that it's just Username, Password and RememberMe, but are there any DataAnnotations being used? Probably, if you're checking the ModelState.

Comment: the logonModel is the one that comes out of the box with a  new mvc project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/11/17/mvc-3-ajax-redirecting-instead-of-updating-div.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious question is, do you have the scripts added to the page you're trying to do this in?  Second, if you're posting to HTTPS (you are, right?), your scripts also have to be HTTPS or you'll get a security error.

Comment: The script are added, and Im using the standard out of the box login code that comes with a new project.